# How to prevent an event from being executed on form load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following code when loading the form

```
 private void LlenarCampos()
        {
            NombreProducto.Text = productos.Nombre;
            ID.Text = productos.Producto_ID.ToString();
            Codigobarrafrm.Text = productos.CodigoBarra;
            Existenciafrm.Text = productos.Existencia.ToString();
            precio1frm.Value = (decimal)productos.Precio1;
            beneficio1frm.Value = (decimal)productos.Beneficio;
            Costo.Value = (decimal)productos.Costo;
            Existenciafrm.Enabled = false;
            ComboCategoria.SelectedItem = CategoriaYPresentaciones.Categoria.fromid(productos.Categoria_ID).Nombre;

        }
```

This code is in charge of filling all the fields of my form as such, but I have two textboxes that, when the EditValueChanged event is executed, make a calculation, how can I prevent this event from happening until the form is filled with the data from the database data and user make the changes?

This is the textbox code:

```
private void precio1frm_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal beneficio = (precio1frm.Value - Costo.Value);
            beneficio1frm.Value = (beneficio / Costo.Value) * 100;
        }
```

Comment: Unregister the events and then re-register them is an option.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, I am contemplating it, but since there are more than 2 text edits, I would have to do it one by one, I think that so far it is the best option

Comment: You can also use a variable to check this... If true dont do this otherwise continue etc. More than a few ways to do it.

Comment: @Trevor Is there any way to ask if the Form_Load event has already been executed? That will be a better solution, so I condition that the code is executed only after loading the form

Comment: And how exactly would you ask whether the `Load` event has been raised? It would require a `if` statement and the way it would be implemented would be to have a field of type `bool` whose value is toggled after the event was raised. Why exactly do you think that would be a better solution than doing exactly the same thing yourself?

Comment: @jmcilhinney If I know that the Load event loads all the necessary information in each textbox, could give way to the EditValueChanged events of each TextBox, because by leaving them enabled and loading each TextBox with the information of the DB, it literally becomes a disaster, but I liked what Trevor plateo, are less conditions, less code and if ,   In case of doing so it would be with an `if` and a  `bool`

Comment: I think you are missing my point. You suggested checking whether the `Load` event had been processed. The only way that could be done would be for you to test a Boolean expression and that Boolean value would ultimately come from a variable somewhere whose value was toggled once the event had been processed. That's exactly what was suggested you do for yourself. There's only one way to do it. The only question is whether it's implemented within the `Form` class itself (it's not) or you do it yourself. It's the same process either way.

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with Trevor's suggestion but your evaluation of it is wrong. Less code? You would need one line per event to detach the event handlers and then one line of code per event to reattach them. So two lines of code per event. If you use a Boolean field, you only need one line of code per event plus one extra line to declare the field and one to toggle it. You'd need less code if you don't attach the events in the designer to begin with, so there's no need to detach them, but that's extra work too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing where you define the event handler, so I assume you are letting the designer do this via the Windows Forms IDE.  So if you look at events for your textbox in designer, you see it there.

What that does, is create this code (or similar):

```
precio1frm.EditValueChanged += precio1frm_EditValueChanged;
```

Find that code (if not sure where it is, right-click the definition for precio1frm_EditValueChanged and choose 'Find all References' or click on the 'references' link just above it.  Cut it from there and paste it at the end of your Form Load code. Repeat for each of the controls as required.

That means the event handler won't be fired until after form load is complete